# passing access token to api call and return value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, openid-connect

As a backend developer I don't have that much experience with angular. I'd like to get access token and send it as a header to my api call. I wrote this method but now I have problem of not returning a value in all the scenarios. I'd appreciate a help to guide for the next step and understand the problem. Here is the code snippets:

```
 public getValues(): Observable<any> {
    this.oauthService.getAccessToken().then(token => {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorizatoin', 'Bearer ${token}');
      return this.http.get<any>(this.systemUrl, {headers: headers});
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **Http interceptor**. Angular interceptors manipulate the headers as they provide features such as authentication and authorization. The angular HTTP interceptors are used to protect the application against XSRF. You can create a file and handle with the implementation of the *HttpInterceptor* like this:

```
@Injectable()
   export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
   Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 

{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if (token) {
      const request= request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    return next.handle(request);}
}
```

You can set your token in your localstorage and create functions to get and set the Token.
For further information checkout the [Angular interceptor documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)
Have a great day! ;)